# VAT refund at Luton

Tags: uk, international-travel, refunds, tax-refunds, vat

I missed the chance to drop the envelope off after security pass as we were rushing for our flight with 2 children. If I return to the UK in a few months time and drop the envelope, will I still get the refund after that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends how few months. [You have three months from purchase to submit your forms](https://www.gov.uk/tax-on-shopping/taxfree-shopping).

> Not all retailers offer tax-free shopping and **you can only get VAT refunds for goods bought within the last 3 months.**

Comment: And given the VAT refund scheme is an EU based scheme if Brexit goes on October the 31st, with who knows what effect on the scheme you may have less than that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Also do I have to amend the departure date? I've already filled out the date. And if I go back again within 3 months, do I have to amend it?

Comment: @Cindee Actually having reread the guidance, I think I've changed my mind. I don't think you can get your VAT refund if you've already exported the goods, since the rules say you might have to [show them to a customs officer when you leave](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/claim-vat-back-on-tax-free-shopping-in-the-uk-notice-7041#section7). If you're in the UK again anyway, you could try asking when you leave, but I think they will tell you that it's too late. Sorry.

Comment: I will be travelling via Luton Airport. And there's no custom officers at the airport so will have to drop the form in a box after security check.